# ASP .net RichTextBox without RequestValidation=False

Tags: c#, asp.net, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

I am trying to submit in an aspx page some formated text through a text box, thus i want to pass Html in the text box in order to save it in the database. Does anyone know any RichText editor for asp .net 3.5 that DOES NOT requires RequestValidation="false" ?

Comment: Use [CodeMirror](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/)

Comment: You can use FreeTextBox. More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075917/isnt-dangerous-if-i-set-validaterequest-to-false/10829591#10829591